# How can I find out what tables were altered in mysql database using phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I made a mistake that may have added a row to a table in mysql database and would like to delete it. Is it possible to find out?

Comment: i think you should search manually.. there is no way to find automatically

Comment: Are you using InnoDB tables, or MyISAM?

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, the mysql client writes a record of executed statements to a history file. By default, this file is named `.mysql_history` and is created in your home directory. To specify a different file, set the value of the MYSQL_HISTFILE environment variable.

in phpmyadmin you can use the url  `//servername/phpmyadmin/querywindow.php`, there is also an icon of database left panel top on clicking that also you can access the history

[image: look at rhe url]